# linking g++ code with shared library build with gcc

Tags: gcc, g++

I made shared library using gcc . I would like to link this library using g++ comiler with source code *.c.
Example

```
test_init.c
#include<stdio.h>
int test_init()
{
   printf(" test init success\n");
   return 0;
}
```

`gcc -shared -o  libtest.so test_init.c`

test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int test_init();
main()
{
   test_init();
}
```

`g++ -I. -L. -ltest test.c`

> /tmp/ccuH5tIO.o: In function `main':
>   test.c:(.text+0x7): undefined
>   reference to`test_init()' collect2:
>   ld returned 1 exit status

Note: If i compile test.c with gcc it works, but i would like to use this approach due to other dependencies. Is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

You call C routines from C++ by declaring them

```
 extern "C" {
     ....
 }
```

Look into a few header files on your system or Google around -- that's the only way to do it because of different function signature systems between the languages.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. in this case both are c files but the executable is making with g++ compiler

Answer (score 1):

As Dirk said, change `extern int test_init();` to `extern "C" { int test_init(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Usually `-llibrary` should be after object files or c/c++ files in gcc command line

```
g++ -I. -L. test.c -ltest
```

The linker searches for the symbols mentioned in test.c after it's processed and when you put `-llib` before test.c, it's just unable to find them.

See `man ld` for more info.

Not sure how the things are when you use `extern`, perhaps something is different in this case.